# How to add more than a single column in a SQL Server table as individual comma seperated values

Tags: sql, sql-server

For one column in a table, I am using

```
STUFF(
    (SELECT distinct 
         ',' + CAST(PF.[PackFeatureListID] as VARCHAR(100))
     FROM 
         [dbo].[PackageFeatures] PF 
     WHERE 
         PF.[PackageID] = @PackageID
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Feature
```

But I need to do the same for 4 other columns in same table. Is there any simple way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms165055(v=vs.100).aspx) MSDN article you have the Concatenate CLR aggregate function as an example. It greatly simplifies concatenating strings. I think that STUFF-XML-PATH thing is awful.

Your problem could be solved easily using the concatenate aggregate function:

```
SELECT dbo.concatenate(Col1) AS Col1Concat, dbo.concatenate(Col2) AS Col2Concat
FROM MyTable
```